# Issue with serve_site() r blogdown

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

I'm using `blogdown` and Hugo to generate a website.

I've created a new R project and have downloaded the theme using:

`blogdown::new_site(dir = "Theme", theme = 'pacollins/hugo-future-imperfect-slim')` and I can preview the template once downloaded. However, if I close R and then restart and I use the add-in "serve site" I get the following error message:

`Error in site_root(config) : 
  Could not find config.toml / config.yaml under...`

and then the directory that the config.toml file is saved in (and all of the rest of the theme files) are listed.

I can't understand what's changing between being able to preview the site in R Studio Viewer, then quitting R and restarting and it not being able to find the config file.

I did find this advice: https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/48 which suggests that my working directory is not the root directory of the website. There are two things I don't understand:

1) How can the the root directory and working directory work together okay when I initially download the theme, until I quit R and restart, and then they appear to not be the same?

2) How to I change the root directory of the website to fix the issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the blogdown's documentation to create a new site with the command "blogdown::new_site(dir="/your/website/dir")", it will set your working directory to "/your/website/dir".

When you restart R/Rstudio, your current working directory is reset (probably to your home directory). You can check the current working directory with  `getwd()`.

The solution is simply set up the working directory:

- The simpler way is to execute `setwd("/your/website/dir")`, then you should be able to run `blogdown::serve_site()`
- The recommended way is to create a Rstudio project at `/your/website/dir` with `File-New Project-Existing Directory`. It will create a `.Rproj` file under the root directory of your website. After that, you can "open project" and work on your website, then preview with `serve_site()`.